# Double SSH then execute NC using Batch file and Plink

Tags: ssh, batch, ssh-tunnel, netcat, plink

Good morning,
I need to execute a netcat command and get the output to do elaboration on my local PC (windows). I just need the "connection good/bad"

Now I use PuTTY using the following step

- Windows -> PuTTY
- PuTTY -> SSH on "Server1" (Linux Suse)
- Server1 shell -> SSH on "Server2"  (Linux Suse)
- Server2 shell -> `nc -zv 10.xx.xx.xx yyyy`

I will like to create a simple script to automate the process, I'm trying to do this via batch and plink. I can use other software or languages ​​but I'm not really expert

I can't install anything on Linux server, since they are live servers and I can't make too many attempts but I have to go without fail.
It is necessary to do these steps for a firewall issue, as server 1 does not see the final server but sees server 2 which in turn sees the final server

I structured the following command but I'm not sure if it works

```
plink -ssh %server1% -pw %password% -no-antispoof -proxycmd "ssh %User%@%server2% -pw %password%" -m commands.txt > result.txt 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

First, to execute an `ssh` command on server1 – to connect to server2 and execute a command there, the syntax is:

```
plink -ssh %server1% -pw %password% -no-antispoof "ssh %User%@%server2% nc -zv 10.xx.xx.xx yyyy" > result.txt 2>&1
```

But you need to pass password to `ssh`. For that, you need to add `-t` switch to `plink` to enable pty and pass the server2's password as an input to `plink`:

```
echo %password2%|plink -t ...
```

Note that this will reveal your server2's password in local machine's process list. But as you are already doing this for server1's password, you probably don't mind. Though the later can be avoided using `-pwfile` switch. And the first, using other kinds of input redirections.